# Can from <module> import * not work sometimes?

Tags: python, import, global

If I have a python module that has a bunch of functions, say like this:

```
#funcs.py
def foo() :
    print "foo!"

def bar() :
    print "bar!"
```

And I have another module that is designed to parse a list of functions from a string and run those functions:

```
#parser.py
from funcs import *

def execute(command):
    command = command.split()
    for c in command:
        function = globals()[c]
        function()
```

Then I can open up python and do the following:

```
>>> import parser
>>> parser.execute("foo bar bar foo")
foo!
bar!
bar!
foo!
```

I want to add a convenience function to `funcs.py` that allows a list of functions to be called as a function itself:

```
#funcs.py (new version)
import parser

def foo() :
    print "foo!"

def bar() :
    print "bar!"

def parse(commands="foo foo") :
    parser.execute(commands)
```

Now I can recursively parse from the parser itself:

```
>>> import parser
>>> parser.execute("parse")
foo!
foo!
>>> parser.execute("parse bar parse")
foo!
foo!
bar!
foo!
foo!
```

But for some reason I can't just run `parse` from `funcs`, as I get a key error:

```
>>> import funcs
>>> funcs.parse("foo bar")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "funcs.py", line 11, in parse
    parser.execute(commands)
  File "parser.py", line 6, in execute
    function = globals()[c]
KeyError: 'foo'
```

So even though `foo` should be imported into `parser.py` through the `from funcs import *` line, I'm not finding `foo` in the `globals()` of `parser.py` when it is used through `funcs.py`. How could this happen?

I should finally point out that importing `parser` and then `funcs` (but only in that order) allows it to work as expected:

```
>>> import parser
>>> import funcs
>>> funcs.parse("foo bar")
foo!
bar!
```

Comment: You should consider using a decorator to enumerate the functions you care about. This would simplify your code greatly.

Comment: @Ignacio how would he go about doing that? I'm not seeing it

Comment: @Rafe: Record the name and function in a registry somewhere, then get the function from the registry instead of scraping through `globals()`.

Comment: getattr(funclib, 'myfunc')() would be straight forward without having to import *.

Comment: @Ignacio I see. Good idea, that would seem to be a rather clean implementation

Answer (score 2):

`import module_name` does something fundamentally different from what `from module_name import *` does.

The former creates a global named `module_name`, which is of type `module` and which contains the module's names, accessed as attributes. The latter creates a global for each of those names within `module_name`, but not for `module_name` itself.

Thus, when you `import funcs`, `foo` and `bar` are not put into `globals()`, and therefore are not found when `execute` looks for them.

Cyclic dependencies like this (trying to have `parser` import names from `funcs` while `funcs` also imports `parser`) are bad. Explicit is better than implicit. Don't try to create this much magic. Tell `parse()` what functions are available.

Answer (score 0):

- Print the globals after you import parser to see what it did
- `parser` is it built-in module also. Usually the built-in parser should load not yours.
  I would change the name so you do not have problems.
- Your importing funcs but parser imports * from funcs?

I would think carefully about what order you are importing modules and where you need them.

Answer (score 0):

Your "parser" is a pretty bad idea.

Do this instead.

```
def execute(*functions):
    for function in functions:
        function()
```

Then you can open up python and do the following:

```
>>> import parser
>>> from funcs import foo, bar 
>>> parser.execute(foo, bar, bar, foo)
```

Life will be simpler without using "strings" where the function itself is what you really meant.

Comment: The example in this question is a little contrived, but I am having the same problem in real-world code where I do have to parse more complicated functions from strings and files.

Comment: @David Dean: Take the hint.  Don't parse strings.  Functions are first-class objects: just use the functions.  If you want partial evaluation or closures or something, just use `functools.partial` or read this: http://effbot.org/zone/closure.htm.  Don't parse strings -- it's a waste of time and needlessly complex.

Comment: The example I've provided here is a minimal example that still has the behavior that is causing the problem. In my actual code I have to parse much more complicated function flow from configuration files created elsewhere (i.e. not just string.split()). I don't have a choice in the matter.

Comment: @David Dean: "I don't have a choice in the matter."  Famous last words.  I'm aware that politics can be challenging.  I'm lifting up an alternative that's considerably simpler and less prone to errors.  You are free to ignore simplicity.